# How to prevent PHP SQL Injection using PHP URL parameters

Tags: php, html, sql, database, security

I have the following code in my index.php :

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["value"])) {
     $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pw", "database");
     $sql = "INSERT INTO table (`value`) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["value"])."')";
     if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Value inserted.";
     } 
     $conn->close(); 
   }
?> 
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input placeholder="example" class="inputfield" type="text" name="value" />
    <button class="button" type="submit"> Submit </button>
    </form>
</body>
```

How can i prevent that someone inserts whatever he likes into the database by sending a post request like this:

```
localhost/index.php?value=whatever
```

Help is appreciated.

EDIT: Question was solved:  it is not possible for an user to put url parameters if server is using "post" requests.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: You are accepting POST request in your code, but want to prevent GET. He can not insert it using get with this code. You should look up a little about SQL injections and form submitting.

Comment: Thank you @equi Looking up and understanding the difference bewteen POST and GET solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accepting POST request in your code, but want to prevent GET. He can not insert it using get with this code. You should look up a little about SQL injections and form submitting